# Can an accelerometer be used to detect heart sound?

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, sound

I've recently come across accelerometer and how it can detect electrical mechanical response. I was wondering can it be used to detect heart sound? Lets say you attach the device close to your chest (where heat lies) and detect sounds and send it over bluetooth? [LPMS-B2 OEM](http://www.omniinstruments.co.uk/lpms-b2-oem.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwyvXPBRD-ARIsAIeQeoHti08JPcuNGUKD9x-BlI_Uy1XLXcVWRV-4YPM_Q3BplXp0wrFHBJIaAvLyEALw_wcB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An accelerometer detects motion (acceleration) of the physical device.

If you can convert the sound of the heart into physical vibration then the accelerometer can detect that vibration.

Converting the tiny amount of sound the heart produces into a large enough vibration for the accelerometer to detect would entail (realistically) using a microhone, amplifier, and speaker, with the accelerometer attached to the speaker cone.

So while theoretically yes, you can do it, practically why would you when you can just use the microphone and amplifier that you'd be using anyway. It's pointless.

So in reality: no, you can't.

Comment: Well said Majenko, I was thinking the same, and quite frankly, most people agree with your reasoning! Cheers!